# Magento: Using APC leads to SimpleXML PHP error

Tags: magento, simplexml, apc

I want to use APC with Magento. I added the folling code in `app/etc/local.xml`:

```
<cache>
    <backend>apc</backend>
    <prefix>MAGE_</prefix>
</cache>
```

but I am getting the error below.
APC is already enabled on the server and working with other sites.

**The error message**

> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   Entity: line 58: parser error :
>   expected '>' in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 645
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>    in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 645
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 645
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 647
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 647
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of
>   non-object in
>   /var/www/html/webkul/magento/partner/app/Mage.php
>   on line 647

What could lead to this error?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Can you copy and paste it?

Comment: Looks like a broken XML file rather than a APC problem, does it not? Have you double-checked the file?

Comment: i installed a fresh copy of magento in my centos system

Comment: @vipinsahu your XML file is broken. This has nothing to do with APC. Check your XML file for errors

Comment: Enormous hint at the XML being incorrect from the key phrases in the error messages: simplexml_load_file() and "parser error".  As @Pekka states, it really doesn't have anything to do with APC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use memcache to provider back cache
that magento can not read config file please makesure you config is correct 
BTW:apc is not compatible X64 OS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your LAMP stack has all of the requirements being met:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Particularly SimpleXML.